# Plugin as optimizer and compiler

Tags: brunch

I'm trying to make a plugin which implements the compile & optimize methods.
In the doc, optimizers and compilers are always in a separated function/class.

Useless I set optimise to true in the config, the compile method is never called.

Is there a way to have both features in a same plugin ?

Edit: I tried `MyPluginCompiler.prototype.defaultEnv = '*';`

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Opened a Brunch issue: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1226

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify either an extension `MyPluginCompiler.prototype.extension = 'someExtension';` or a pattern for your plugin? Either one of these is *required* for a compiler, so that brunch knows what files to pass to the compilers.

I could not reproduce the issue. I created a repo with a simple plugin that is both a compiler and an optimizer for js files: https://github.com/goshakkk/brunch-plugin-optim-n-comp/blob/master/my-brunch/index.js

You can see it prints both `1` and `2` when building the supplied `demo` app https://github.com/goshakkk/brunch-plugin-optim-n-comp/tree/master/demo

https://github.com/goshakkk/brunch-plugin-optim-n-comp

If that does not fix your issue, please comment on this thread https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1226